# client server communication app run on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, client-server, httpclient

i am making client server app for android where client is android and server is local server.
it runs on emulator successfully but not on device. it actually not crashes but gives response from server

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">

    <h1>ERROR</h1>
    <h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
    <hr/>
    <P>
     While trying to retrieve the URL:
    <A HREF="http://10.0.2.2/test/testing.php">http://10.0.2.2/test/testing.php</A>
    <P>
     The following error was encountered:
   <UL>
       <LI>
            <STRONG>
         Connection to 10.0.2.2 Failed
         </STRONG>
     </UL>
         <P>
     The system returned:
     <PRE><I>    (110) Connection timed out</I></PRE>
         <P>
         The remote host or network may be down.  Please try the request again.
            <P>Your cache administrator is <A HREF="mailto:webmaster">webmaster</A>. 
     </div>
           <!--
          -- Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new
          -- feature to Internet Explorer.  If the text in
           -- an errors message is too small, specifically
           -- less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns
           -- its own error message.  Yes, you can turn that
           -- off, but *surprise* its pretty tricky to find
          -- buried as a switch called smart error
           -- messages  That means, of course, that many of
           -- Resins error messages are censored by default.
           -- And, of course, youll be shocked to learn that
           -- IIS always returns error messages that are long
           -- enough to make Internet Explorer happy.  The
           -- workaround is pretty simple: pad the error
           -- message with a big comment to push it over the
           -- five hundred and twelve byte minimum.  Of course,
           -- thats exactly what youre reading right now.
         //-->
         </body></html>
```

i am using httpclient and url is 10.0.2.2 and also using internet permission and usb debugging in on. i just want to run on device. is there any setting i have to change on mobile device or change in android project like in android manifest file or any idea.

Comment: Type http://10.0.2.2/test/testing.php into your phones browser and see if you can get to it. Is your phone connected to the same network or are you using 3/4g?

Comment: no its not opening after one minute, it says "Data connectivity problem.. the server failed to communicate. try again later"

Comment: firewall is off. still saying same message.

Comment: Try opening the URL with your phone connected to your local network. Then you might see the problem.

Comment: its works on live server but i want to run it on local server.....

Answer (score 0):

The emulator works because it is on the same network as the computer. If you want to use the URL on your phone you will have to connect to your server's network. You are using a **local** IP address so you should be on the same network. This would use your phone's wireless connection.

The other thing you could do is use your **external** IP address so that you do not need to be on the same network. You should Google the specifics, but I think your just need to find your **external** IP address ([whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/)) and make sure the port you want to connect to is open in the router's settings (usually port 80). This would let you use your phone's 3G or 4G.

Comment: No problem, was this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem on my `node.js server`

Here how I solved this problem:

1. Open `Control Panel` on your PC
2. Click on `System and Security` 
   [image: Screenshot]
3. Below `Windows Defender Firewall` click on   `Allows app through windows firewall` 
   [image: Screenshot]
4. Find `Node.js server-side Javascript` and mark it correct 
   [image: Screenshot]